# "Determine" Vs "Specify"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, verbs, word-difference

In the following self-made examples can use both "specify" and "determine and as far as I know and dictionaries give some instances, I guess they are interchangeable in this sense. I just need your confirmation.

> - People should be allowed to **specify** their own destinies and future.
> - People should be allowed to **determine** their own destinies and future.

Do you agree that above sentences mean the same thing? If no, please explain why.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example of how to understand the nuance of any particular word by looking at all its related words, especially with regard to any common origin.  In this case:

> [specify](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=specify):  *specific, specification, specimen, special, species, etc.*

All these words have in common the idea of *uniqueness*, that there is something particular that separates them from the rest.  You should imagine that the verb "specify" also includes the desire to select one, unique option from the rest.

> [determine](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=determine):  *determination, determined, determinate, determinant, etc.*

All these words have in common the idea of *limits* -- that by "determining* something we have set the limits of what it involves.  It's less about making a specific choice, and more about setting the boundaries of what that choice must include.

With regard to your example sentence, we could paraphrase:

> People should be allowed to pick for themselves the destiny (or destinies) they want, from the overall set of possibly destinies
>
> People should be allowed to *set the limits* of what they want their destiny to be.

Naturally there is some overlap in these definitions.  In real-world terms there's not much difference in what these *mean*, but there is a slight difference in *focus* and *intent*.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the two sentences in question:

(1)  *People should be allowed to **specify** their own destinies and futures*.

(2)  *People should be allowed to **determine** their own destinies and futures*.

English is a very complex language, which is one of its best qualities.  My Grandfather, who was born in Austria, was a professor of linguistics at a major U.S. university.  He often stated that English was, by far, the hardest language he ever had to learn. Why?  Because the myriad of words -- and the placement of grammatical symbols -- chosen by English writers can change the meaning of a sentence in extremely subtle ways.

In the first sentence, the word "specify," in this context, strongly suggests that the writer is confident about his or her future path and, due to this confidence, can clearly explain which path they've decided to follow in the future.

The second sentence, on the other hand, suggests [a bit less confidently] that the writer believes in the freedom to search for a future path that works best for him or her.  Yes, there's only one word that changes when comparing these two sentences, but that demonstrates just how subtle our language can be ... so, no, these two sentences do not have the same overall meaning.